# Digilent Basys 2 using TinyOS-nesC

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, xilinx

I wonder if it is possible to use the TinyOS-nesC environment to program a Basys2 card? Digilent has developed a driver for this card under Linux but their technical department says that it utilizes Xilinx-VHDL programs for Basys2. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand that the Basys2 card is an FPGA-based card, not a microcontroller? You have to use an HDL (such as Verilog or VHDL) to program the FPGA.

If you program the FPGA to contain (possibly among other things) a microprocessor, then you might be able to use the TinyOS/nesC programming environment on that processor. You would have the choice of either porting nesC to, say, the Microblaze CPU that Xilinx provides (such a port may already exist, but it's hard to tell with a casual search), or implementing a CPU in the FPGA that already has nesC ported to it.

Comment: Hello Dave,
Thank you for your quick response. In reality, I did know that the card Basys2 is an FPGA. I posted my question in the microcontrollers group in a hurry without knowing the FPGA's group exist. As I said before, I've just discovered this forum. But I admit that this is not really a good excuse. So if I understand, the best way to program Basys2 is to use VHDL? I've heard that the VHDL code is to long run. Is there a way to optimize the VHDL code to make it run faster?

Comment: VHDL (and Verilog) are hardware description languages (HDLs). They are used to describe the hardware you want to create in the FPGA. The languages themselves are not "fast" or "slow" -- the performance of the system depends on the the actual hardware architecture that you describe using them.